# Presto lag dates, group/partitioned by id

Tags: sql, group-by, presto, lag, partition

Say that I want to find every time that a client updated their budget.

Here's what my data looks like

```
datetime, client_id, new_budget
__________,__________,___________
2022-01-01,1,        ,100
2022-01-01,2,        ,300
2022-01-02,1,        ,80
2022-01-02,2,        ,80
```

And the code I've run.

```
SELECT datetime AS dt_1,
       LAG(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY client_id, datetime) AS dt_2,
       client_id,
       new_budget
FROM budget_table
```

What I'm expecting returned will be

```
dt_1,      dt_2,      client_id, new_budget
__________,__________,__________,___________
2022-01-01,NULL,      1         , 100
2022-01-02,2022-01-01,1         , 80
2022-01-01,NULL,      2         , 300
2022-01-02,2022-01-01,2         , 80
```

Hence there are NULL values for dt_2 in the first entry of each client_id. I'm not sure what code will accomplish this effect; is a GROUP BY clause will be necessary (or a partition over clause.)

But here's the output to the SQL that I ran

```
dt_1,      dt_2,      client_id, new_budget
__________,__________,__________,___________
2022-01-01,NULL,      1         , 100
2022-01-02,2022-01-01,1         , 80
2022-01-01,2022-01-02,2         , 300
2022-01-02,2022-01-01,2         , 80
```

So the huge issue here is that it's not recognizing that the dt_2 should be NULL if the previous row is from a different client_id.

Which syntax is recommended to accomplish this effect?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Second code block @GuruStron

Comment: And the sample data?

Comment: _" I'm not sure if this code accomplishes this effect"_ - have you tried running it?

Comment: I have run it and have logged the results, which are unsatisfactory. (Also added sample data.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [partition by](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#functions-window--page-root) `client_id`:

> The `PARTITION BY` clause separates the input rows into different partitions. This is analogous to how the `GROUP BY` clause separates rows into different groups for aggregate functions. If `PARTITION BY` is not specified, the entire input is treated as a single partition.

```sql
SELECT datetime AS dt_1,
       LAG(datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY datetime) AS dt_2,
       client_id,
       new_budget
FROM budget_table
```